# Nvidia card for CUDA and AMD for system

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, gpu, amd-graphics

I have a system with a AMD 5700XT GPU and I have bought a Nvidia card for developing CUDA applications.

I use Archlinux and I have tried to install nvidia, cuda, nvidia-utils and nvidia-settings packages to run CUDA stuff, but when I do that, I get a completely black screen and I have to go to terminal mode and remove those packages in order to restore my desktop.

When removing those packages, lsmod shows that nouveau and amdgpu modules are loaded. Of cuorse, nouveau isn't enough for running CUDA applications. When I try it, it says the following

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL.
```

I would like to know how should I configure the system and install drivers in order to get the propietary Nvidia driver to run CUDA applications while I do all the OpenGL/Vulkan stuff through the AMD card.

Comment: How did you install NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: why dont you pci pass through? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF

Comment: What is the PCI passthrough? Never heart about it!